# Uncertain about answers computing area and volume of sphere with unusual metric.

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider the a metric in a three dimensional space given by

$$ ds^{2} = \frac{dr^{2}}{1-\frac {2}{r}} + r^{2} (d\theta^{2} + sin^{2} (\theta) \: d\phi^{2}) $$

Calculate:

a) The area of a sphere with coordinate radius $r=R$.

b) The volume of a sphere with coordinate radius $r=R$.

For part a) my answer was $r=R \Rightarrow dr=0$ and $A(\mathbb{S}^{2})= \int _{\mathbb{S}^{2}} \sqrt { |g|} dA = \int _{\mathbb{S}^{2}} R^{2}sin (\theta) \: d\phi \wedge d\theta = 4 \pi R^{2}$

For part b) my answer was $V(\mathbb{S}^{2})= \int _{\mathbb{S}^{2}} \sqrt { |g|} dV = \int _{\mathbb{S}^{2}} \sqrt {\frac {r^{5} sin^{2} (\theta)}{r-2}}d\phi \wedge d\theta \wedge dr = 4 \pi \int_0^R \sqrt {\frac {r^{5}}{r-2}} dr$

My question is: Am I manipulating correctly the metric and volume(area) differential forms? Are my answers ok? I'm having some doubts in my answers; for example in part a) I arrive at the usual area of a sphere with radius $R$ but the metric is not the usual induced metric for the sphere in $\mathbb{R^3}$. Can someone elaborate on this please? Any comments would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The induced metric on the sphere is $R^{2} (d\theta^{2} + sin^{2} (\theta) \: d\phi^{2})$ and coincides with the usual Euclidean metric in spherical coordinates, hence unsurprisingly the area you get is the same $\int _{\mathbb{S}^{2}} \sqrt { |g_{{\mathbb{S}}^{2}}|} \, d\theta\wedge d\phi =4\pi R^2$.

The volume integral is also as you wrote: instead of integrating just $r^2$ we are left with the less pleasant  $\int _V \sqrt { |g|} \, dr\wedge d\theta\wedge d\phi=4\pi\int_0^R r^2 \sqrt{\left|\frac {r}{r-2}\right|} \, dr$.

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept your answer. Do you have any geometrical insight to this metric? How can I make sense of the metric of the sphere plus the $g_{rr}$ term?

Comment: Edited: the absolute value under the square root was missing. Not sure about a physical meaning of such a metric. This metric could define a *metric tensor* only if the manifold doesn't include the $R=2$ as it has to [vary smoothly from point to point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor#Definition). It'd define a pseudo-Riemannian manifold on a ball of smaller radius, the distances along r-rays being negative. Some [relativistic metric tensors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor_%28general_relativity%29) may have similar signature at least.